# Others ways to say "I wish you the best in your decision"

Tags: phrase-requests, synonyms

I'm writing a business letter. Wondering if there are other ways to say "I wish you the best in your decision" (already used it in a recent letter to the same person).

Found "I wish you well in your decision."

Also found the following somewhat related topics. Interesting, but no cigar:

["Best of luck" or "Best luck"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20377/best-of-luck-or-best-luck)

[Wishing someone that something goes easily for them](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26163/wishing-someone-that-something-goes-easily-for-them)

[What is the neutral way of telling someone to "do whatever you want"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/151622/what-is-the-neutral-way-of-telling-someone-to-do-whatever-you-want)

Grateful for your help.

Comment: old navy term:  carry on

Comment: 'I wish you xxxx in your decision' doesn't make much sense in English. Can you rephrase it?

Comment: Something like "Whatever your decision, all the best in your future endeavors" or "Whatever you decide, I wish you all the best in the future." (Is this a case where you're asking for somebody to make a decision such as offering them a job, but wish to extend best wishes whether they take it or not?)

Comment: Possible duplicate: ["Best of luck" or "Best luck"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20377/best-of-luck-or-best-luck) / [All the best vs best of luck](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25701/all-the-best-vs-best-of-luck) / [How should I convey my best wishes?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/246910/how-should-i-convey-my-best-wishes) / etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

I wish you the best in your endeavors.